# MVC routing parameters not working at all

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I've looked for a solution to this but even the simplest examples aren't working properly. Passing a single parameter {id} works successfully but that's the only parameter that is working. Changing the single parameter to anything else fails. In the example below multiple parameters also fail. It seems as the only workable parameter is "id".

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
          name: "Servers",
          url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}/{a}",
          defaults: new
          {
            controller = "Test"
          }
        );
    }

public class TestController : Controller
{
  [HttpGet]
  public ActionResult Monster(string id, string a)
  {
    return Json(new { success = id }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
  }
}
```

The url localhost/Test/Monster/hi Successfully reads the parameter as "hi". Specifying localhost/Test/Monster/hi/hello fails and gives a 404.

Comment: sorry to say but as you saying localhost/Test/Monster/Hi working mean only one parameter routing is configured... did you try but restarting the IISExpress as routing get loaded on very first call .. you after making the changes in routing you have to stop the IIS Express from the Icon Tray and  re-run you project then with one paramter it should throw error as you have not set these option it will work only when u specify both the paramteres.

Comment: I think something else is going on here. Any chance you could upload a complete project somewhere? Other things to check are your IIS configuration, and make sure you've recompiled.

Comment: Oh the reason I say that is because the request with only an id shouldn't work, because a is not marked as optional.

Comment: @IanNewson its not necessary to mark id as optional..

Comment: @IanNewson I think you're correct about something else going on here. I'm going to look into possible configuration issues now.

Comment: @DeepkSharma care to provide evidence?

Comment: Please post your `Application_Start` method (or wherever you have your call to `RegisterRoutes`). Are you using Areas, Attribute Routing or WebApi? If so, please post those routes as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very late response but the issue with this was that there was an area being registered further downstream that was causing the routing issues. The area being registered had an optional url parameter that was taking the routes over. Utilizing this registered area fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
          name: "Servers",
          url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}/{a}",
          defaults: new
          {
            controller = "Test",
            id = UrlParameter.Optional,
            a = UrlParameter.Optional 
          }
        );
    }
```

Also, is this your only route?
The order that the routes are set-up in is important, it's very easy to overwrite a route with a later route. I have done that mistake countless times.

Comment: This is the only route, I believe it's an external issue at this point. I've tried your changes as well but haven't reached a resolution. I appreciate the help.

Comment: Only the last parameter can be optional, but in any case the parameters are typeof `string` which are nullable so `UrlParameter.Optional` is unnecessary (they are both 'effectively' optional - they will be `null` if not provided)

Answer (score 0):

In case action is not optional, you should specific the default value for it. Please try :

```
routes.MapRoute(
          name: "Servers",
          url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}/{a}",
          defaults: new
          {
            controller = "Test",
            action = "Monster"
          }
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

In your method you have specified the parameter string a so when you pass the URl localhost/Test/Monster/hi/hello MVC will look for the parameter a in the url as it matches the form post parameters with the parameters in the function

So this link might help you as it helped me

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/299531/Custom-routes-for-MVC-Application

Answer (score -1):

sorry to say but as you saying

> localhost/Test/Monster/Hi

working mean only one parameter routing is configured... did you try by restarting the IISExpress as routing get loaded on very first call and one time only..

after making the changes in routing you have to stop the IIS Express from the Icon Tray and re-run you project then with one parameter it should throw error.. as you have not set these option it will work only when u specify both the parameters.

Comment: Restarting the server hasn't had any effect on it.

Comment: if one parameter is working fine mean, your routing is not effective.. mean its not hooked up with Server. as you have not specified parameters as optional mean if you do not pass second parameter it will give you error. it will work only and only with both parameters together, what is your case can't say but this is the way how it should work.proper compilation is also required before restarting and rerunning the project..

Comment: This is not correct. The route parameters are `string` which is nullable. `Test/Monster` will mean the value of `id` and `a` will be null,  `Test/Monster/hi` will mean the value of `id` will be "hi" and the value of `a` will be null. `Test/Monster/hi/hello` means the value of id will be "hi" and the value of `a` will be "hello".

Comment: @StephenMuecke right..!! thanks to make me correct.. right they both will be null.. I admit my mistake.